# retrieve date format from machine settings

Tags: sql, t-sql

how do i retrieve the date format of the machine the script is running on

```
declare @inputdate varchar(25)
declare @datetemp datetime

select @inputdate = '3/13/2012'

select @datetemp = CAST(@inputdate as DATETIME)

select @datetemp
```

here's the scenario: i have a date string coming in and i need to format a usa date in a customized way (mm/dd/yyyy am/pm) vs the other dates in other parts of the country (which might be dd/mm/yyyy 24:hr)

so i need to find a way to get the machine's date format setting.

Comment: This is normally done client-side... are you working on a website, a windows app, or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the machine's date format setting is not really what you want.  When you run a query on the server, it uses the language setting of the logged in user.  There is a way to get the dateformat of the logged in user...

```
Select DateFormat 
From   sys.syslanguages 
Where  name = @@Language
```

This will return the dateformat.  For us_english, it returns 'mdy'.

Comment: what do i have to change (on my server or during install) to make the default dmy dateformat. i want to simulate a machine that's from another country?

Comment: You can change the default language for all the logins and also change the default language for new logins.  See here:  http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DataDesign/setting-a-standard-dateformat-for-sql-se

Answer (score 1):

Relying on the machines regional settings at the SQL Level would be a rather strange way of doing it (especially for server / client scenario as any SQL would get the servers setting). For instance, rather than relying on CAST to convert your string to a date, you should be a little bit more specific by specifying what format the source string is. For example:

```
DECLARE @inputdate VARCHAR(25) 
DECLARE @datetemp DATETIME
SELECT  @inputdate = '13/03/2012'  
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME,  @inputdate, 103)  --### 103 = DD/MM/YYYY input date
SELECT  @inputdate = '03/13/2012'  
SELECT  CONVERT(DATETIME,  @inputdate, 110)  --### 110 = MM/DD/YYYY input date
```

Note how two different input dates can be converted to the same day by telling SQL what format the string is in. It would be up to your interface to either restrict the user to a certain date format or determine the regional settings and pass this to SQL & have SQL implement the correct style parameter accordingly.

Comment: my problem there is this is a sql script file.sql and i'm not sure how to get that information into the sql script from ui code (c# setup program.exe)

Comment: That sql script file must be ran against a SQL instance though? as soon as you do that, any SQL that did scrape regional settings would scrape the servers settings, not the client... If you want to stick with *.sql files - you're just going to have to edit them to include format codes as per my answer.